# Using the property Depth in Django Rest Framework serializers

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

When I use the Depth property in a serializer that brings the user model reference, it brings the user's password field, would there be any way to remove the password from the request response?

my response:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xO1x2.png)

Answer (score 2):

Define Serializer for user and exclude password field and use this serializer in views and then access this new view to show depth.